# How to declare per-instance properties for instances rendering on a shader graph?

Tags: unity, instancing, unity-shader-graph

Unity Version: 2019.4.1f1

Render Pipeline: URP

I created a shader using Unity's Shader Graph, and I want to apply GPU Instancing on this shader, but there is no way to declare per-instance properties inside the shader graph.

Is there a way to make GPU Instancing work on shader graphs' materials?

Comment: It looks like [the SRP Batcher](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/02/28/srp-batcher-speed-up-your-rendering/?_ga=2.39445731.1507695196.1594054488-2121096744.1463615920) is intended to replace the previous instanced rendering behaviour. Have you considered using a custom node in your shader graph to look up per-material properties from `cbuffer UnityPerMaterial` inside your graph?

Comment: @DMGregory No, how can i do that? could you write an answer please.

Comment: If I had an answer for you, I'd have posted that instead of a comment. All I have to offer you at the moment are potentially useful avenues of exploration.

Comment: I can't say for certain but I think I remember something about using MaterialPropertyBlocks in scripts was supposed to get around the instancing issues. But I could be wrong, this might have just been to increase performance when transferring data to the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the GPU Instancing in the inspector directly on the material you created:

[image]

Comment: I did, but changing the material's properties will break the Instancing.